# Could an ASP.NET web application assembly be replaced during its run

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an ASP.NET web application (Visual Stuido project type) in which everything is compiled into a single assembly, it is deployed in IIS. My question is if I have a new version of the assembly, is OK to replace it in IIS without bringing down the IIS? Or for a safe consideration, should I firstly shutdown the web server and then replace the assembly and restart? I am looking for a better solution to reduce server down time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. but it will cause an immediate Application Pool Recycling.

Quoting [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx):

> Altering the following files will also trigger an immediate restart of the application pool:
>
> - web.config
> - machine.config
> - global.asax
> - **Anything in the bin directory or it's sub-directories**

Answer (score 1):

We've reinstalled applications numerous times usnig the Visual Studio installer and it has replaced the assemblies with no problems.  The only thing we find is that the first time we open the web page it takes a little while to open - possibly as it reads in the new assembly.  We haven't had to to do an IIS reset or anything like that.

In addition on our dev environments (and because I am lazy) I often simply overwrite the assembly on the web server and that exhibits the same behaviour as above.

Taking down IIS is not an option for us, as we have many websites running on the same server.

I can't guarantee this is the best way to do it or that it won't cause problems, but it works for us.

Comment: thanks for your sharing. Now, I know I am the only one do assembly replacing :-)